# Retrieving the paths for all pages viewed by a user in a session

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I'm trying to examine what percentage of visitors to my site visit **two or more** of the set of pages A, B, C, and D during a single session.

My hope is that I can do this by using the API to pull a list of all paths visited, grouped by session, and then doing my own parsing of the data.

Is this possible? Thanks!